# End application from class library project

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I close or end the application from library project?

For example I have made a function in a library project to check if SD Card is available or not. So if sd card is not available i want to display a dialog box with button. On button click I want to close the application. I tried finish() but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

u need to provide permission to use sdcard in your manifest. if the device doesn't have a sdcard the android os takes care of it and it doesn't allow to install the application.

Comment: I am not installing the application in SD card. I am able to check if SD card is available or not. After checking if card is not available i want to force user to close the application with dialog.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>     provide this permission in your manifest and try to run it on qa device with no sd card

Answer (score 0):

You can close the application by getting the process id.. the below code would help you

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```